# How to solve this eliptic equation?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I want to find a solution to

$$ \frac{x_1}{x_2 + x_3} +\frac{x_2}{x_1 + x_3}  + \frac{x_3}{x_1+x_2} = 4 $$

for $x_1,x_2,x_3>0$, and $x_1+x_2+x_3=1$.

We have
$$\frac{x_1}{1-x_1}+\frac{x_2}{1-x_2}+\frac{1-x_1-x_2}{x_1+x_2}=4.$$

Let $\dfrac{x_1}{1-x_1}=s,\dfrac{x_2}{1-x_2}=t,$then $x_1=\dfrac{s}{1+s},x_2=\dfrac{t}{1+t}.$
We then have $$s+t+\dfrac{1-st}{s+t+2st}=4,$$
and $s=x+y,t=x-y,$then$$\frac{4 x^3+3 x^2-4 x y^2+y^2+1}{2 \left(x^2+x-y^2\right)}=4$$
$$y^2=\frac{4 x^3-5 x^2-8 x+1}{4 x-9}$$
which eventually simplifies to solving $$y^2 = x^3 + 121 x^2 + 1144 x + 2704.$$
How can we solve this? I am unfamiliar with eliptic curves, even after reading some basic material, it seems each equation is tackled differently. Is there a routine method for equations like this?

Comment: You seem to also assume $x_1+x_2+x_3=1$.

Comment: Assuming $x_1+x_2+x_3=1$, we can factorise $x^3+121x^2+1144x+2704$ - hint: substitute $x=-4$, and divide the equation by (x+4).

Comment: Are the $x_i$ supposed to be rational numbers ?

Comment: @Peter Yes rational

Comment: @CCZ23 There is mistake in equation when making $s,t$ substitution. And you don't need to make $x,y$-substitution. You can express one of $s$ and $t$ in terms of another from quadratic equation. If I haven't mistake in my calculation problem becomes the following: find positive integer pairs $(p,q)$ such that $(q+2p)(6q-p)(2q^2+7pq-2p^2)$ is square of an integer. Here $s=\frac{p}{q}$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu  I  get the same;   I found a few pairs with $\gcd(p,q) = 1.$ ////  28224 =  2^6 3^2 7^2      q:  5   p:  2  ////
2304 =  2^8 3^2      q:  2   p:  3  ////
1225 =  5^2 7^2      q:  3   p:  11  ////
33124 =  2^2 7^2 13^2      q:  4   p:  11  ////
43277313024 =  2^10 3^2 11^2 197^2      q:  70   p:  541  ////
409478409025 =  5^2 7^2 47^2 389^2      q:  143   p:  1033  ////

Comment: There is a formula for any coefficient. It allows for some solution - to get the next solution.  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264754/solution-to-a-diophantine-equation/275193#275193

Comment: See the answer by Michael Stoll at [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227713/estimating-the-size-of-solutions-of-a-diophantine-equation) for finding these points on the elliptic curve.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x_3 = 1-x_1-x_2.$  We get
$$(6-7x_1)x_2^2+(-7x_1^2+13x_1-6)x_2+6x_1^2+1-6x_1=0$$

Since $x_2$ must be rational number then discriminant must be square number.

Hence we get

$$V^2 = 49U^4-14U^3-59U^2+16U+12\tag{1}$$
with $$U=x_1$$
An equation $(1)$ is birationally equivalent to the elliptic curve
$$Y^2 + XY + Y = X^3 - 234X + 1352 \tag{2}$$
with $$U = \frac{-X-3}{X-23}, V = \frac{-52Y-26X-26}{(X-23)^2}$$
According to [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/910/a/4) , elliptic curve has rank $1$ with generator $(8,-1).$

Let $P(X,Y)=(8,-1)$ then $13P$ gives positive solution using group law as follows.

$x_1 = \frac{360580518798960218928732302909807349160733186141387092674568680456952454542061941533770232294581808506248091531}{5049549479055895370585527032143752370420166865650725292672977625843429614339787186642533620730887839277641883695}$

$x_2 = \frac{306595938811259225832173528708283063181310906692288470156330531143167380161534287576910178181384187701055520003}{2212455878539701410315253838580846315686580343082895422240759011653186431824457611838047222821239666672118415365}$

$x_3 = \frac{3852086946706166284829913202913539977730505088064544668668081343553155180751922744069311820918853233969099047039}{4875970872038496234103522347007495376171052920878501712857733921453635116079760054850598705847152516034789194083}$

Comment: "Since $x_2$ must be rational number then we get quartic below". Why?

Comment: Consider the quadratic equation for $x_2$, then discriminant must be square number.

Comment: I still don't understand how equation (1) is derived sorry. Is this taken straight from line one of my question? or taken from the eliptic curve equation i gave?

Comment: I added a quadratic equation for $x_2$.

Answer (score 0):

First notice that x=0,y=52 is a solution.  Take a tangent to the curve at this point and it will necessarily intersect at another rational point.   By successively taking intersections of the curve with either tangents of rational points or the lines passing through two different rational points you can find more rational points.